# Dynamic casting in SV using $cast function and task

Tags: oop, casting, system-verilog, test-bench

How can we tell if the calling of *$cast* is of a function or of a task. How would calling of each differ? One thing I understand is that with the function call, I'll be able to use *assert()*. But other than that, what tells us if the call is of the *$cast* function or the *$cast* task? In either case, we'd be doing something like *$cast(pkt, pkt1);*

LRM gives the syntax of the *$cast* function as

```
function int $cast( singular dest_var, singular source_exp );
```

and of the *$cast* task as

```
task $cast( singular dest_var, singular source_exp );
```

and goes on to explain that

> Use of $cast as either a task or a function determines how invalid assignments are handled.
>
> When called as a task, $cast attempts to assign the source expression
> to the destination variable. If the assignment is invalid, a run-time
> error occurs, and the destination variable is left unchanged.
>
> When called as a function, $cast attempts to assign the source expression
> to the destination variable and returns 1 if the cast is legal. If the
> cast fails, the function does not make the assignment and returns 0.
> When called as a function, no run-time error occurs, and the
> destination variable is left unchanged.

Please explain.

Comment: or is LRM loosely trying to say that use of assert() or if block around the $cast would choose the $cast function, otherwise $cast task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your comment is correct: if $cast is used as part of an expression, it is considered called as a function. That wording is derived from Verilog terminology when functions could only be used in an expression and never could exist as a simple statement like a task call. But once SystemVerilog added functions with void return types, that wording does not fit as well anymore.